# how to use different color for backcolor in textbox?

Tags: c#

how use  color random for textbox back color?

```
textbox1.backcolor = color.**random**;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eh, something like that?

```
private static Random s_Gen = new Random();
...

// Controls couldn't be (semi-)transparent, so alpha must be 255
textBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, Color.FromArgb(s_Gen.Next()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Random`-class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx). You can get all known colors from the [`System.Drawing.KnownColor`-enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
KnownColor[] colors = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(System.Drawing.KnownColor));
colors = Array.FindAll(colors, c => c =! KnownColor.Transparent); // is not allowed
Random r = new Random();
KnownColor randomColor = colors[r.Next(colors.Length)];
textbox1.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(randomColor);
```

Note that you should not call this code in a loop, otherwise it will generate always the same "random" number because it is seeded with the current time. Instead re-use the same random instance. So, if it's in a loop declare and initialize the random variable outside of the loop.